ADF Data Preview OR CI/CD Pipeline mapping columns Issues after deployment
I am experiencing unexpected behavior in Azure Data Factory (ADF)'s data preview while working on a data flow. The data preview continues to show older data even after refreshing it. I have to turn off and turn on the data flow debug to view the updated data. How can I resolve this issue and ensure the data preview reflects the most recent changes immediately?
Furthermore, I am encountering issues during CI/CD pipeline deployment of ADF changes from my developer environment to production:
In some data flows, certain columns on the Sink side are either removed or unselected in the mapping after deployment.
During execution, some data flows fail without any clear reason, but when I copy the activities to a newly created pipeline, the issue is resolved and the pipeline runs successfully.
How can I troubleshoot these issues?


The data preview continues to show older data even after refreshing it.

If your data is not updating once Import the projection as follows:

If you are unable to preview updated data after importing projection, clear your browser cache, caching, data flow and features can cause the issues may cause above issue. Along with that manage Azure Data Factory studio preview experience.
About your CI/CD Pipeline, column mapping and execution failure might be the main issues. For more information you can refer to below documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-manage-studio-preview-exp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide.md


You can check similar question in MS Q&A.
